# Superclass can not be cast to subclass in one example, while casts smoothly in another example. Why?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, casting, classcastexception

**Edit # 1** add at the bottom of the question.

---

I got the ClassCastException in an Android project, but the problem seemed to be in the domain of Java, so I wrote the following SSCCE. In this SSCCE, I get the following exception on `PVC parentViewHolder = (PVC) holder;`:

```
Exception in thread "main" Overridden onBindViewHolder in my ExpandableRecyclerAdapter called.
java.lang.ClassCastException: practice_programs.inheritance.class_cast_to_super.RecyclerView$ViewHolder cannot be cast to practice_programs.inheritance.class_cast_to_super.ParentViewHolder
    at practice_programs.inheritance.class_cast_to_super.ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.java:9)
    at practice_programs.inheritance.class_cast_to_super.ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.main(ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.java:15)
```

*As you can see in the code given, we are trying to cast a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` to `ParentViewHolder` (which is actually a subclass of `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`)*

---

***Although I do understand that Superclass can not be cast to subclass, but my confusion is the following:***

The Android project that I am working on actually uses [this ExpandableRecyclerView](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view) implementation as a library project. **In this project, the same thing happening does not cast any problems.** That is see [Line # 146 on in this class](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view/blob/master/expandablerecyclerview/src/main/java/com/bignerdranch/expandablerecyclerview/Adapter/ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.java) in which `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` is being cast to `ParentViewHolder` which, [you can see on Line#19 here](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view/blob/master/expandablerecyclerview/src/main/java/com/bignerdranch/expandablerecyclerview/ViewHolder/ParentViewHolder.java), extends `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.

---

***SSCCE:***

```
public class ExpandableRecyclerAdapter<PVC extends ParentViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        System.out.println("Overridden onBindViewHolder in my ExpandableRecyclerAdapter called.");
        PVC parentViewHolder = (PVC) holder;//EXCEPTION***************************************
        super.onBindViewHolder(parentViewHolder, position);
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        new ExpandableRecyclerAdapter().onBindViewHolder(new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(), 1);
    }

}
```

**ParentViewHolder.java**

```
public class ParentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    String string = "XAR!";

}
```

**RecyclerView.java**

```
public class RecyclerView {

    public static class ViewHolder {}

    public static class Adapter {
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
            System.out.println("onBindViewHolder of RecyclerView.ViewHolder called."); 
            System.out.println("The string of the passed viewHolder is " + ((ParentViewHolder) viewHolder).string); 
        }
    }
}
```

**_____________________________________________________________________________**

**EDIT 1:**

Another piece of information that may be important is that according to my needs, I made a tiny change to [ExpandableRecyclerAdapter](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view/blob/master/expandablerecyclerview/src/main/java/com/bignerdranch/expandablerecyclerview/Adapter/ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.java):

1. Line # 119 and Line # 123 are method calls in the method body of `onCreateViewHolder` method which receives an argument `int viewType`. I added this `viewType` argument to the calls to `onCreateParentViewHolder` and `onCreateChildViewHolder` on Line#119 and Line#123.
2. In accordance with ^, I add the `int viewType` arguments to the corresponding method declarations on Line#187 and Line#195

Comment: From what I see, their version should cause an exception when passed the wrong type, but I would guess that it does not happen at all in their project due to either always checking the type before passing or other class invariants.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove Can you see my edit, and tell me if you think what I changed could cause a problem?

Comment: Those are two abstract methods, I don't know all the locations they are implemented, but adding the extra parameter to be used as a guard like `onCreateViewHolder` in every implementation of those two abstract methods should not break anything I would imagine as long as the guard you pass matches the the type passed. The idea of an int enum as a guard to identify the other parameter's type is a bit odd when they could just do a `instanceof` check instead.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove "to be used as a guard like onCreateViewHolder " - what do you mean by "guard like onCreateViewHolder" ?

Comment: I meant as a value you check to determine the holder type, to guard against casting the holder type incorrectly.

Comment: Can I help in some other way than already stated in my answer? Your text (in bold, about casting) is wrong - the casting is possible. The problem is caused by putting an object of a wrong class in the adapter view, and the only suggestion that can be given (unless you tell us what you are trying to accomplish) is - do not cast objects to types that they do not posses.

Comment: @fdreger "The problem is caused by putting an object of a wrong class in the adapter view" - right! I reached that conclusion after a lot of headache.  "unless you tell us what you are trying to accomplish" - I wrote a [detailed question about that here](http://www.java-forums.org/android/94992-classcastexception-third-party-library-after-i-tried-fiddle-my-code.html) - Please also see the answers I have written there. If you can answer that, let me know so I can copy that question here on SO as well.

Comment: Your question, as stated above, is answered. The question you link to could be titled "how to use the expandable recycler view library with custom view types" - and I think you should simply put in on SO as a separate question. I might be able to answer that, but I will not know until I read it in SO format.

Comment: @fdreger Adding the question here. About the answer, I am sorry, I had upvoted it but forgot to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @fdreger Just added the question [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648760/how-to-use-expandablerecyclerview-library-with-multiple-child-viewtypes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a wrong mental picture of what "casting" is - you seem to imagine that casting changes class of an object. This never happens!

Casting only allows us to reveal the true type of an object that is referenced by a variable of superclass type. This is sometimes necessary, because in Java both references and objects have types, and they do not have to exactly match.

In this example `mySuperRef` is a reference of type `MySuper`, but it really points to an object of type `MySub`. That's why we can cast it to reveal the true type:

```
MySuper mySuperRef = new MySub();
MySub mySubRef = (MySub)mySuperRef;
```

In this example, the same cast will give as an error, because the "true type" of an object referenced by `mySuperRef` is different:

```
MySuper mySuperRef = new MySuper();
MySub mySubRef = (MySub)mySuperRef;
```

To wrap it up: in Java you can only cast an object to a type that the object already has. Casting does not allow us to modify objects in any way, it is only used to assign the object to it's proper reference variable.