# How to use ExpandableRecyclerView library with multiple (child) viewTypes?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need an Activity with an expandable RecyclerView like the one in this picture:

[image]

So I am using [**this third party library project**](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view) . **That part works.**

*The **problem arose** when I did what I am describing in the next two paragraphs:*

**My next requirement is** that I want different child-rows for different parent-rows. I am reproducing (if that's the right word) [**this example to create multiple child-viewholders**](http://doublewong.com/2014/create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type/).

***Description of Example:*** The idea is basically to have the different Child-viewholders (corresponding to each child-row style) extending one common childview-holder, and then inside our ExpandableRecyclerAdapter where we are passed the ArrayList of the data displayed in parent-rows in the constructor (`parentItemList` in the SSCCE), we declare constants representing all the child-row-types (TYPE_EDITTEXT and TYPE_SPINNER in the SSCCE below); and then inside `getItemViewType(int position)` we compare the data item from `parentItemList` using the passed `int position` as the index, with each text string on parent-rows and in each case, assign the `viewType` int variable a TYPE constant, and the `viewType`.Then this `int viewType` is passed to the `onCreateChildViewHolder` and `onBindChildViewHolder`, so we execute another switch-block in the definitions of each of these methods and then in onCreateChildViewHolder we return a corresponding ChildViewHolder (inflated from a corresponding layout resource) (either `R.layout.custom_row_child_with_edittext` or `R.layout.custom_row_child_with_spinner` in the SSCCE) ; and in `onBindChildViewHolder`, update the data according to the case in the switch-block.

**The problem is the dollowing ClassCastException:**

```
07-26 18:21:54.380: E/AndroidRuntime(276): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 18:21:54.380: E/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.ClassCastException: tests.test.epmc_mobile.search_module.no_ui.expandable_recycler_view.EPMCChildViewHolder
07-26 18:21:54.380: E/AndroidRuntime(276):      at com.bignerdranch.expandablerecyclerview.Adapter.ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.java:144)
```

The thing is that [ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.java](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view/blob/master/expandablerecyclerview/src/main/java/com/bignerdranch/expandablerecyclerview/Adapter/ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.java) is a part of the third party library project, and Line#144 (and 142 and 143 which I added) are:

```
Log.i(TAG, "+++++++++++++++++++++++++THE TYPE OF THE RecyclerView.ViewHolder WHICH HAS BEEN PASSED AS AN ARGUMENT IS "
                    + holder.getClass().getSimpleName() + "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
            PVH parentViewHolder = (PVH) holder;
```

Before I tried to do what I am doing above, it was working fine.

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private static int [] imageIds = {R.drawable.ic_action_call, R.drawable.ic_action_copy, R.drawable.ic_action_discard};
    private static String [] titles = {"Dummy Text One", "Dummy Text Two", "Dummy Text Three"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate of MainActivity called.");//check
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mainActivity_recyclerView);

        MyExpandableRecyclerAdapter myExpandableRecyclerAdapter = new MyExpandableRecyclerAdapter(this, populateDataList(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myExpandableRecyclerAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this)); 
    }

    private ArrayList<ParentObject> populateDataList(Context context) {
        Log.i(TAG, "populateDataList of MainActivity called.");//check
        ArrayList<ParentObject> parentObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<imageIds.length && i<titles.length; i++) {
            MyCustomParentObject myCustomParentObject = new MyCustomParentObject(context);
            myCustomParentObject.setImageId(imageIds[i]);
            myCustomParentObject.setTitle(titles[i]);
            parentObjectList.add(myCustomParentObject);
        } 
        return parentObjectList;
    }
}
```

**MyExpandableRecyclerAdapter.java**

```
public class MyExpandableRecyclerAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerAdapter<ParentViewHolder, ChildViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = MyExpandableRecyclerAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    Context context;
    private List<ParentObject> parentItemList = new ArrayList<>();

    private static final int TYPE_EDITTEXT = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SPINNER = 1;


    public MyExpandableRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<ParentObject> parentObjectItemsList) {
        super(context, parentObjectItemsList);
        Log.i(TAG, "Constructor of MyExpandableRecyclerAdapter called.");//check
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        parentItemList = parentObjectItemsList;
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        int viewType;
        if (parentItemList.get(position).equals("EditText Entry")) {
            viewType = TYPE_EDITTEXT;
        } else {
            viewType = TYPE_SPINNER;
        }
        return viewType; 
    }




    @Override
    public MyParentViewHolder onCreateParentViewHolder(ViewGroup container, int viewType) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateParentViewHolder of MyExpandableRecyclerAdapter called.");//check
        Log.i(TAG, "IN onCreateParentViewHolder, THE TYPE OF AN ITEM IN THE parentItemList IS " + parentItemList.get(1));
        return new MyParentViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_parent, container, false));
    }



    @Override
    public MyChildViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup container, int viewType) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateChildViewHolder of MyExpandableRecyclerAdapter called.");//check
        switch(viewType) {
        case TYPE_EDITTEXT:
            return new MyChildViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_child_with_edittext, container, false), context);
        case TYPE_SPINNER:
            return new MyChildViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_child_with_spinner, container, false), context);
        default:
            return new MyChildViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_child_with_edittext, container, false), context);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindParentViewHolder(ParentViewHolder parentViewHolder, int position, Object parentObject) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBindParentViewHolder of MyExpandableRecyclerAdapter called.");//check
        MyParentViewHolder myParentViewHolder = (MyParentViewHolder) parentViewHolder;
        MyCustomParentObject myCustomParentObject = (MyCustomParentObject) parentObject;
        myParentViewHolder.textView.setText(myCustomParentObject.getTitle());
        myParentViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(myCustomParentObject.getImageId()); 
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindChildViewHolder(ChildViewHolder childViewHolder, int position, Object childObject) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBindChildViewHolder of MyExpandableRecyclerAdapter called.");//check

        switch(childViewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
        case TYPE_EDITTEXT:
            MyChildViewHolderWithEditText myChildViewHolderWithEditText = (MyChildViewHolderWithEditText) childViewHolder;
            myChildViewHolderWithEditText.textView.setText("TextView " + (position+1) + " Title"); 
        case TYPE_SPINNER:
            MyCustomChildObject myCustomChildObject = (MyCustomChildObject) childObject;
            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myCustomChildObject.getSpinnerItems());
            arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            MyChildViewHolderWithSpinner myChildViewHolderWithSpinner = (MyChildViewHolderWithSpinner) childViewHolder;
            myChildViewHolderWithSpinner.spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    }

}
```

**MyCustomParentObject.java**

```
public class MyCustomParentObject implements ParentObject {
    private static final String TAG = MyCustomParentObject.class.getSimpleName();
    //List to store all the children of the parent object in.
    private List<Object> childObjectList;
    private String [] bib;

    MyCustomParentObject (Context context) {
        super();
        bib = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinner_options);
    }


    @Override
    public List<Object> getChildObjectList() {
        Log.i(TAG, "getChildObjectList of MyCustomParentObject called.");//check
        //"You can either return a newly created list of children here or attach them later"
        return populateChildObjectList();
    }

    @Override
    public void setChildObjectList(List<Object> childObjectList) {
        Log.i(TAG, "setChildObjectList of MyCustomParentObject called.");//check
        childObjectList = childObjectList;
    }

    private List<Object> populateChildObjectList() {
        Log.i(TAG, "populateChildObjectList of MyCustomParentObject called.");//check
        childObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
        MyCustomChildObject myCustomChildObject = new MyCustomChildObject();
        myCustomChildObject.setSpinnerItems(bib);
        Object myCustomChildObjectCasted = (Object) myCustomChildObject;
        childObjectList.add(myCustomChildObjectCasted);
        return childObjectList;
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private int imageId;
    private String title;
    public int getImageId() {
        Log.i(TAG, "getImageId of MyCustomParentObject called.");//check
        return imageId;
    }
    public void setImageId(int imageId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "setImageId of MyCustomParentObject called.");//check
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        Log.i(TAG, "getTitle of MyCustomParentObject called.");//check
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        Log.i(TAG, "setTitle of MyCustomParentObject called.");//check
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

**MyCustomChildObject.java**

```
public class MyCustomChildObject {
    private static final String TAG = MyCustomParentObject.class.getSimpleName();

    private String [] spinnerItems;

    public String [] getSpinnerItems() {
        return spinnerItems;
    }

    public void setSpinnerItems(String [] spinnerItems) {
        this.spinnerItems = spinnerItems;
    }

}
```

**MyCustomParentViewHolder.java**

```
public class MyParentViewHolder extends ParentViewHolder {
    private static final String TAG = MyParentViewHolder.class.getSimpleName();
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;

    public MyParentViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Log.i(TAG, "Constructor of MyParentViewHolder called.");//check
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.parentCustomRow_textView);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.parentCustomRow_imageView);
    }

}
```

**MyCustomChildViewHolder.java**

```
public class MyChildViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder {
    private static final String TAG = MyChildViewHolder.class.getSimpleName();

    public MyChildViewHolder(View itemView, final Context context) {
        super(itemView);
        Log.i(TAG, "Constructor of MyChildViewHolder called.");// check
    }
}
```

**MyCustomChildViewHolderWithEditText.java**

```
public class MyChildViewHolderWithEditText extends MyChildViewHolder {
    EditText editText;
    TextView textView;

    public MyChildViewHolderWithEditText(View itemView, Context context) {
        super(itemView, context);

        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.childViewHolderWithEditText_TextView);
        editText = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.childViewHolderWithEditText_editText);
    }

}
```

**MyCustomChildViewHolderWithSpinner.java**

```
public class MyChildViewHolderWithSpinner extends MyChildViewHolder {
    Spinner spinner;

    public MyChildViewHolderWithSpinner(View itemView, Context context) {
        super(itemView, context);

        spinner = (Spinner) itemView.findViewById(R.id.childViewHolderWithSpinner_spinner);
        //ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.childViewSpinnerFields, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        //adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ///spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {}
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By comparing [Line#13 of this stack-trace of the error free program](http://pastebin.com/ehTJnAax), and [this one of the program which results in the exception](http://pastebin.com/abXDwXf2), and by looking at the `onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType)` method definition on [Line#117 of this `ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.java` class](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view/blob/master/expandablerecyclerview/src/main/java/com/bignerdranch/expandablerecyclerview/Adapter/ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.java), from which I infer that `onCreateViewHolder` is being passed the wrong `viewType` parameter.

But I haven't yet been able to figure out why!

---

I think **I have figured it out.**

Actually the trick of `TYPE_SOMETHING` constants that I am using in `MyExpandableRecyclerAdapter` is the same one they have used in `ExpandableRecyclerAdapter`, i.e. in my `MyExpandableRecyclerAdapter`, `0` is the value of `TYPE_EDITTEXT` and `1` is the value of `TYPE_SPINNER`; whereas in their `ExpandableRecyclerAdapter`, which is extended by my `MyExpandableRecyclerAdapter`, `0` is the value of `TYPE_PARENT` and `1` is the value of `TYPE_CHILD`.

If the Android framework passes the same `viewType` parameter to `onCreateViewHolder` which is returned from `getItemViewType(int position)`, it will pass `1` if it was `TYPE_SPINNER` in my `MyExpandableRecyclerAdapter`, but their `ExpandableRecyclerAdapter` will understand it as `TYPE_CHILD`, and thus call `onCreateChildViewHolder`.

**So I think the whole thing I am trying to achieve can't be done. =(**